# Jquery and php not working to load images onto screen from folder

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a folder with images in it and I am trying to load the images from this file onto the webpage. I know the images are in correct format and the dir are all correct.  The images are just not appearing on the page.  This is my html file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "loadImages.php",
        dataType: "json",
        alert("This is working");
        success: function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(i, filename) {
                $('#imgs').prepend('<img src="' + filename + '"><br>');
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<html>
    <body>
     <div id="imgs">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php file.

```
<?php
$filenameArray = [".png"];

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/images/');
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
            array_push($filenameArray, "/images/$file");
        }
    }

echo json_encode($filenameArray);
?>
```

All I need is the images to be shown on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be concatenating your variables correctly

`array_push($filenameArray, "/images/$file");`

Needs to be:

`array_push($filenameArray, "/images/".$file.");`

If you're still having issues, could you post your json?